# vim - python autoindent not working correctly when set in .vimrc

Tags: python, vim

I am having issues with my `.vimrc` file: 
I am correctly writing python code. But I have indentation issue.
When I put is in my .vimrc file:

```
" indentation python
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py
    \ set tabstop=4
    \ set softtabstop=4
    \ set shiftwidth=4
    \ set textwidth=79
    \ set expandtab
    \ set ts=4
    \ set sw=4
    \ set ai
    \ set autoindent
    \ set fileformat=unix
    \ set expandtab ts=4 sw=4 ai
```

But as soon as a python file is open, if I run `set expandtab ts=4 sw=4 ai`
vim will start-indent correctly when select code and hit `S-=`.
Any idea?

Comment: what is excatly your problem? It is not clear. Your vimrc is a mess, you set multiple values twice. Vim does not automatically correct the indendation, you have to command it try to typ `gg=G`

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo sorry for the messy things. I have tried so much thing and finally it didn't work as expected. Basically, vim indentation is not indenting my python script correctly. when I try to set dynamically with `: set expandtab ts=4 sw=4 ai` vim indent with 4 spaces(it is what I want). But when I try to add this code to my `.vimrc` file so that it works for every *.py file, it just doesn't work.

Comment: dmx now i understand, and I would gladly help you, but Amadan has given you a way better answer than i could. So please read his answer an ask if you need further help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a valid syntax in Vim. `\` only cancels the newline, it does not let you chain commands (you have `|` for that). What you wrote is equivalent to (truncated to just a subset of your options):

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py set tabstop=4 set softtabstop=4 set shiftwidth=4 set textwidth=79
```

which obviously doesn't make sense, since `set` is not a valid option.

So you can either do

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py
  \ set tabstop=4
  \     softtabstop=4
  \     shiftwidth=4
  \     textwidth=79
```

(make it a single `set` command with multiple settings), or you can do

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py
    \ set tabstop=4 |
    \ set softtabstop=4 |
    \ set shiftwidth=4 |
    \ set textwidth=79
```

(make it multiple `set` commands).

However, this is bad practice, since the options will be set globally; e.g. if you load a JavaScript file then a Python file, then go back to your JavaScript buffer it will have your Python settings. You should prefer to use `setlocal` instead.

Also, it generally makes sense to use `FileType python` instead of `BufNewFile,BufRead *.py` - maybe not specifically in Python's case, but some languages can have multiple extensions.

And finally, this allows you to clean up your `.vimrc` by placing your language-dependent settings in `.vim/after/ftplugin/python.py`. You don't need `autocmd` there - just write your `setlocal`, and be secure in the knowledge that your settings will be executed for each buffer of `python` filetype.

Thus, my final recommendation:

```
" .vim/after/ftplugin/python.py
setlocal tabstop=4
setlocal softtabstop=4
setlocal shiftwidth=4
setlocal textwidth=79
setlocal expandtab
setlocal autoindent
setlocal fileformat=unix
```

or equivalently

```
" .vim/after/ftplugin/python.py
setlocal ts=4 sts=4 sw=4 tw=79 et ai ff=unix
```